# Azure insights: 'requests' item type are only stored with success=='False'

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have Azure durable function run by timer trigger, which runs another function (UploadActivity) that does some http call to the external to Azure REST service. We know for sure that small percentage of all `UploadActivity` invocations end up in http error and exception risen, the rest are exception-free and upload some data to the remote http resource. Interesting finding I got is that Azure Insight's 'requests' collection contains only failed requests, and no successful one recorded

```
// gives no results
requests
| where success == "True"


// gives no results
requests
| where success <> "False"


// gives results
requests
| where success == "False"
```

I can't realize why. Here are some attributes of one of returned request with success=='False' if it helps to find why

```
operation_Name:
UploadActivity 

appName:
/subscriptions/1b3e7d9e-e73b-4061-bde1-628b728b43b7/resourcegroups/myazuretest-rg/providers/microsoft.insights/components/myazuretest-ai

sdkVersion:
azurefunctions: 4.0.1.16815
```

'resource' is defined in Azure as http call to http-triggered function, but I have no http triggered functions in my app which makes things even more confusing, I think maybe these requests belong to Azure Insights calls, that could be also built based on Azure Functions

Comment: What is the result of `requests | summarize count() by success`?

Comment: @Peter it's the same as number as if I run `requests
| where success == "False"`, meaning all records in the given period. Displays

`> False 996`

Comment: Then probably there are just no successful calls. Unless there is some kind of filter defined in the source application or the status is set to false even if the result is ok. I think you can rule out sampling since that doesn't filter out just the successful requests

Comment: there are successful calls, I can see them in "dependencies" collection in Insights with http status code = 200, and I can see data in the destination. It just does not go to 'requests' for some reason, no filter that I set explicitly, only if something set Azure behind the scene

Answer (score 0):

For a timer triggered function it is normal that there are no records in the `requests` collection of Application Insights. If it would be an http triggered function you would have 1. Only the request that triggers the function is recorded as a request in Application Insights. A timer trigger does not respond to a request.

Once the function is triggered all http requests (and all kind of other communication like calls to service busses etc.) executed by that function will be recorded as a [dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies) in the `dependencies` collection. This is [by design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation#data-model-for-telemetry-correlation) and is how Application Insight works.

Comment: That makes sense, the only thing I'm missing here is why then failed executions are recorded as [request]. I could understand "all" or "nothing" situation, I just can't get why failed only

Comment: Can you share the url that is logged?

Comment: Hi @Peter, I do not see any url that stored in any of the requests, the only couple of fields that vaguely resembles url are `appName` and `_ResourceId`, there values are equal and you can see it in the description of the question. Thanks

Comment: @YMC can you get any info using `requests
| project url, operation_Name, cloud_RoleInstance, cloud_RoleName, operation_SyntheticSource`? Sometimes the roleinstance and rolename can identify what resource is causing the request. Also, operation name as well. SyntheticSource can indicate the request being caused by a watchdog.

Comment: I got results, but `url` and `operation_SyntheticSource` are empty (blank),  cloud_RoleInstance is some sort long alpha-numerical identifier, and operation_Name is same as in the question description.

Comment: @YMC and what about `cloud_RoleName`? It sure is mysterious ...

Comment: cloud_RoleName = myazuretest-ai, which is a name of Application Insights resource I use for these requests. I think might be these `requests` come not from function app, but from application insights linked to it, maybe it records itself besides function app it linked to